# Three-variable interpolation in java similar to matlab interpn() or interp3()

Tags: java, math, vector, interpolation, spatial-interpolation

**1.** Consider six different vectors `float[] xRef, yRef, zRef` and `float[] xTest, yTest, zTest`, representing a positions grid. For each set of the `Ref` and `Test` vectors a vector `dataRef` and `dataTest` exist that hold data for the respective mesh.

**2.** My goal is to interpolate test data that are on a grid represented in the `Test` vectors onto the `Ref` vectors and currently I have a Matlab code in the form of

```
[ yMsh, xMsh, zMsh ] = meshgrid ( yRef, xRef, zRef );
finalTestMesh = interp3 ( yTest, xTest, zTest, origTestMesh, yMsh, xMsh, zMsh );
```

**3.** My questions: Are there any suitable java api's available? If not then I am asking for suggestions to a solution. So far my own attempts either fail and/or are too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to give the Michael Thomas Flanagan's Java Scientific Library a chance. The TriCubicSpline Class page is found at http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/TriCubicSpline.html